# Full username is not displayed after logging in

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, wcf, stored-procedures

We are using DotNet WCF. This is DEV Code. When we pointed Dev database to TEST, it shows full username. So, I think there is issue with the WCF or the the stored procedure's out parameter is not completely taken in by the WCF code. Also, I think there's no issue with the WEB app since, I pointed endpoint address of test in DEV web.config and it shows full username.

**WcfServiceSVC.cs logic:**

```cs
public string GetEmpName(int employeeID)
{
    var credLogic = new Logic.Credentials.CredentialsLogic();
    var empName = credLogic.GetEmpName(employeeID);
    return empName;
}
```

**Credentials Logic:**

```cs
public string GetEmpName(int employeeId)
{
    string empName = string.Empty;

    Database abcDatabase;
    DbCommand abcCommand = null;

    try
    {
        abcDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(abcConnectString);

        abcCommand = abcDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("abc.ws_get_web_empname");
        abcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // in
        abcDatabase.AddInParameter(abcCommand, "p_emp_id", DbType.VarNumeric, employeeId);

        // out
        abcDatabase.AddOutParameter(abcCommand, "p_emp_name", DbType.String, 65);

        // run
        abcDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(abcCommand);
        empName = abcDatabase.GetParameterValue(abcCommand, "p_emp_name").ToString();

        //Added:
        //empName = abcCommand.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
        //Log("EmpId=" + employeeId.ToString() + ", EmpName: " + empName);
    }
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```sql
create or replace procedure ws_get_web_empname
     (
        p_emp_id     in number,
        p_emp_name   out varchar2
     )
  as
  begin

       select name_formatted_pcl
     into p_emp_name
         from people
         where people_id = p_emp_id;
       exception
         when NO_DATA_FOUND then
           p_emp_name := '';    
  end;
```

Output is showing only First name. Not full name.
Let me know if you need further info to help me solve the issue.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? That SQL you've provided isn't valid T-SQL, and would generate multiple errors if you tried to run it on a SQL Server instance.

Comment: in your query, the column "name_formatted_pcl" holds  employee name, which you return as p_emp_name. 
In table can you confirm value under column name_formatted_pcl?

Comment: @VishalPawar, yes, the people table under name_formatted_pcl column user name contains full name as: "Julia Kurakula". But in the DEV site, it only shows Julia. Instead of Full name.

Comment: Then tag [[tag:oracle]] *not* [[tag:sql-server]]. SQL Server and Oracle are *completely* different products.

Comment: It's more likely your data is different between the two databases. Log into Oracle and directly query PEOPLE table to confirm it's apples and apples.

Comment: @JuliaKurakula : Can you declare length for the variable as 50 (p_emp_name   out VARCHAR2(50)) and test. May be due to default length, name might trim down

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, name in the database is Full Name: 'Julia Kurakula'. The EmpName function in the .NET is supposed to fetch the full user name from the stored procedure based on the ID passed after validating it. And there is only one user name mapped to the user ID passed. But the name displayed on the website is only first name: "Julia".

Comment: debug the stack, what does your .NET code do with the name once it's retrieved from the database via your PL/SQL? Something 'bad' it would seem.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, after the username is retrieved from the database it is supposed to be displayed on the site.